# Django: how to annotate queryset with count of filtered ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django novice question :)

I have the following models - each review is for a product, and each product has a department:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16)
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, db_index=True) 
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, db_index=True) 
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

I'd like to make a Django query for a date range (2012-01-01 to 2012-01-08) and return a list of all departments, annotated with department ID, and the number of products from that department that were reviewed during that date range.

This is frying my brain a bit :)

I can get all the reviews for a time range:

```
 reviews = Review.filter(time__range=["2012-01-01", "2012-01-08"])
```

Then I guess each review has a product field, and each of those products has a department code. But how can I group them by product and code, with counts and department IDs?

Alternatively, is it best to request the departments, and then annotate them with product counts, somehow?

Comment: You unaccepted my answer - can I assume that it didn't work correctly? If that's the case, why was it wrong, did you get it working another way, and can you post your solution as an answer to help others in the future?

Answer (score 46):

Avoid `extra` and `raw` whenever possible. The [aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) have nearly this use case:

Straight from the docs:

```
# Each publisher, each with a count of books as a "num_books" attribute.
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
>>> pubs
[<Publisher BaloneyPress>, <Publisher SalamiPress>, ...]
>>> pubs[0].num_books
73
```

So, to modify this for your particular example:

```
depts = Department.objects.
            filter(product__review__time__range=["2012-01-01", "2012-01-08"]).
            annotate(num_products=Count('product'))
```

The function calls on separate lines is just for readability and you should move them about accordingly. I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Pretty sure this'll be a FieldError.  Cannot resolve keyword 'product' into field. Choices are: code

Comment: @KrisF You're probably right - I was looking for the reverse relation count.. I'd have to experiment with actual code to get it working correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a problem just like this - I'm pretty sure a raw query is going to be necessary.

Comment: unrelated question: why the `Book` table became lowercase `book` in the `Count()` ?

Comment: After spending some time playing with the ORM, I better understand this problem. It isn't currently possible without using extra, or doing multiple queries.

Comment: @HananN. because you're referencing the `field` not the `Model`.

Comment: Wait now I'm confused. In my scenario I have CourseProject --> CourseUnit --> Course which is analogous to OP's Review --> Product --> Department.

I can do the following query to get a list of Courses, annotated with the number of CourseUnits which satisfy some condition based on the CourseProjects they contain (analogous to OP's goal):

Course.objects.filter(courseunit__courseproject__number__gt=1).annotate(num_units=Count('courseunit'))

Which is "Get all courses and annotate them with the number of units they contain for which have a project with number > 1".

Django 1.5

Comment: @dshap It does seem possible now.  I'm not sure if it was possible in Jan '13.  Django 1.5 hadn't been released yet.  Perhaps it was made possible then.  I could swear I was bashing my head against the wall trying to solve this.  Maybe I overlooked it or maybe it was new.  Either way, have an upvote.  This answer should probably be marked accepted now.

Comment: I tried the approach on similar data model and it didn't work. The issue is that it joins with product and review on filtering ARE DIFFERENT with joins on annotation.
This will work as expected.
Department.objects.extra(where=["<review_table_name.time_field> BETWEEN <time1> AND <time2> "]).           
            annotate(num_products=Count('product'))

Comment: Why does this STILL have the most upvotes when it is clearly wrong, and the first comment clearly explains why.

Answer (score 12):

In django `>= 2.0` this could be achieved with

```
depts = Department.objects.all().annotate(
    num_products=Count('product', filter=Q(product__review__time__range=["2012-01-01", "2012-01-08"]))
)
```

For more info read docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Answer (score 5):

I've had to do a couple of similar queries in the last few days and the easiest way it to use the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) queryset function to annotate each object in your queryset with a filtered count of the products:

```
start = ..  # need to be formatted correctly
end = ...
departments = Departments.objects.all().extra(select = {
     'product_count' : """ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appname_department
                           JOIN appname_product
                               ON appname_product.dept_id = appname_department.id
                           JOIN appname_review 
                               ON appname_review.product_id = appname_product.id
                           WHERE appname_review.time BETWEEN %s AND %s
                       """
}, params=[start, end])
```

and

```
{% for department in departments %}
    {{ department.product_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this example is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: It's always a good idea to avoid raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The Docs for aggregation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

There probably is a way to use aggregate or annotate, but I prefer this:

```
departments = Department.objects.all()
for dept in departments : 
    # Get the number of reviewed products for a given range and department
    num_products = dept.product_set.filter(review__time__range=["2012-01-01", "2012-01-08"]).count()
```

if you absolutely need it as a function of the model:

```
class Department(models.Model) :
    ...
    def num_products(self, start_date, end_date) : 
        return self.product_set.filter(review__time__range=[start_date, end_date]).count()
```

### EDIT

I think that if you were to do a raw query (something like this)

```
sql = """SELECT COUNT(Product.*) as num_products, Department.*
    FROM Department
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Product ON Product.department = Department.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Review ON Product.id = Review.product
    WHERE Review.time BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2012-01-08"
    GROUP BY Department.id"""

Department.objects.raw(sql)
```

and then num_products will be an attribute on every Dept instance in the results.

you may need to play with the field + table names a little

Comment: Blergh. One query per department.

Comment: OK I added a solution that does only one query

Comment: It's always a good idea to avoid raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with similar data model.

My solution was like:

```
 Department.objects \
.extra(where=["<review_table_name.time_field> BETWEEN <time1> AND <time2> "])\
.annotate(num_products=Count('product__review__product_id'))
```