# Django annotation Count including zeroes

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a queryset annotation in Django (1.5), but I want it to include 0 values as well as a time query and can't figure out how.

Say I have a Post model, with an FK to user:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateField()
```

I want to retrieve the number of Posts annotated by a user:

```
User.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts'))
```

This works just fine.
However, as soon as I try to filter on the created date, eg:

```
User.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts')).filter(posts__created__gt='2013-01-01')
```

I only get back users who have made posts.  It looks as though Django adds a SQL join, which therefore only returns ones with a join to that table.

I'm about to resort to two queries and combining them in Python.

Is this possible in the Django ORM?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean if you want to combine two querysets, that is simple, since queryset is just a list. I believe you understand the result from your query, that makes sense. If you want all the users (have posts or not). Just retrieve all the users as queryset 1, and find out who has posts as queryset two. Then flag the user in list 1 who is also in lsit 2. I am not sure I fully understand you problem.

Comment: I want to filter this query:  User.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('posts')) by Post date, without losing the users who have 0 posts.

Comment: Is the intent to count only posts created after Jan 1, 2013?  Otherwise the query seems to boil down to 'filter all users to just those with 0 or more posts after Jan 1, 2013'.  Which is everyone.

Comment: If I'm right about what you're trying to do, take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418522/django-how-to-annotate-queryset-with-count-of-filtered-foreignkey-field?rq=1  - the bottom line is that the ORM doesn't do that directly, and you'll have to either write the SQL query using a left outer join yourself or do the Python combination.