# Annotate and count django

Tags: django

I have a Word model, it has many to many relation with Phrase model
I want to get rid of this loop because it's not effective in terms of performance:

```
for w in words:
    w.freq = w.phrases.count()
    w.save()
```

I know I should use annotate and subquery, I have found this question
[Django: how to annotate queryset with count of filtered ForeignKey field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418522/django-how-to-annotate-queryset-with-count-of-filtered-foreignkey-field)
But don't really understand how I should do it in my case

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449960/django-save-vs-update-to-update-the-database

Comment: @TyC If you give a try and read my question just a little bit more carefully, you will see, that it doesn't have anything regarding update vs save but The question was about the loop